# keep just index of memory table in memory

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

There is a stored procedure that performs some computation.

I need to have a high performance lookup mechanism to detect duplicates, memory table gives me a good performance, but it is unreasonably memory hungry.

I have a two column table which has an index on these two columns, like that:

```
create temporary table my_cache (
 col1 varchar(10) not null,
 col2 varchar(15) not null,
 index my_cache_idx using hash (col1, col2)
) engine=memory
```

I have following data and index sizes:

```
data size: 832.79 mb
index size: 333.51 mb
```

These results are from part of computation (actually they are even bigger). I like speed of index size growth, but I don't like data size growth and I don't need data at all.

I tried to use myisam table with high `key_cache_size` (2G) and create index on it, but its performance is much worse (with memory table I get about 50000 records per second and with myisam table it is only 6000 per second).

Are there any approaches to mitigate memory consuptions while keeping performance high?

Comment: Do you need to detect duplicates and use their info, or do you just want to *prevent* duplicates from going into that table? How's the table being populated - many inserts from a single process or are inserts coming from multiple processes? Are you able to use transactions (because if yes, InnoDB will blow MyISAM)? Are you using an SSD by any chance or is it a mechanical drive in question? Also, how about using the memory table but only have the hash column, without an index?

Comment: @N.B., there is only one process populating `my_cache` table (stored procedure). Index from that table is used to filter out rows which will cause duplicates (e.g. `select * from other_t t where not exists (select * from my_cache c where (t.col1, t.col2) = (c.col1, col2)`). I would like not to mess with drives because they are definitely slower than memory. Will memory table without index be as fast as with index? It has about 50 millions of rows.

Comment: Since you're using Memory engine with hash index, it appears you can do without the index since it won't benefit for the queries. [Here's a good read about some details about MySQL engines](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11099/is-innodb-engine-up-to-speed-against-memory-engine), make sure to take a good look at Rolando's answer, there's also a mention on why the drive is actually important even for memory engine.